# React - How to Update State After AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I've been tinkering with converting one page in my web application to use react rather than jQuery and Vanilla JS but I'm getting stuck on how to approach it because of how unfamiliar I am with react.

At the moment, on the page I have an html table with rows that relate to a database table and another column with links to edit and delete the rows.

This is done by opening bootstrap modals containing a form which is populated for the appropriate row for the edit action and a delete modal to confirm the deletion, there is also a link on the page to add a new row, also via AJAX, so what I am trying to do is replicate this in react but I can't seem to understand how to go about it.

At the moment I have this (I am using a generic component name (`ModelName`) for this example to avoid confusion from what it is actually called.):

```
var ModelNames = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {model_names: this.props.model_names};
  },

  render: function() {

    var rows = [];

    this.props.model_names.forEach(function(model_name) {
      rows.push(<ModelName model_name={model_name} key={model_name.id} />);
    });

    return (

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr role="row" className="heading">
                <th>Property 1</th>
                <th>Property 2</th>
                <th className="text-center">Options</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ModelName = React.createClass({
  handleRemoveModelName: function() {
    $.ajax({           
      url: '/model_name/ajax_delete', 
      data: { model_name_id: this.props.model_name.id },
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,           
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({ model_names: data }); // this is the part I am having trouble with
      }.bind(this),
      error: function() {
        console.log('error');      
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <tr id={"model_name_" + this.props.model_name.id}>
        <td>{this.props.model_name.property_1}</td>
        <td>{this.props.model_name.property_2}</td>
        <td className="text-center">
          <a href="javascript:;" className="btn btn-xs" onClick={this.handleEditModelName}><i className="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> <a href="javascript:;" className="btn btn-xs" onClick={this.handleRemoveModelName}><i className="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  // this comes from Rails
  <ModelName model_names={<%= @model_names.to_json %>} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

The deletion via ajax works fine and the server side responds with all the rows in the database table (after the deletion has taken place), so the json response is in exactly the same format as the initial data provided on the page load, I am just trying to figure out how to update the state so that react knows to remove the record I just deleted.

Similarly, I want to then extend it to replicate my editing and creation CRUD features but I am struggling to find the information I need after reading a number of blog posts.

**Update**

```
var ModelNames = React.createClass({
  handleRemoveModelName: function(id) {
    $.ajax({           
      url: '/model_name/ajax_delete', 
      data: { model_name_id: id },
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,           
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({ model_names: data });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function() {
        console.log('error'); 
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    this.props.model_names.map(function(model_name) {
      return (
        <ModelName 
          model_name={model_name}
          key={model_name.id}
          onRemove={this.handleRemoveModelName}
        />
      );
    }, this);

    // ...
   }
});

var ModelName = React.createClass({
  handleRemoveModelName: function() {
    this.props.onRemove(this.props.model_name.id);
  },
  // ...
});
```

Also, just to try and include everything relevant, the delete button still has `onClick={this.handleRemoveModelName}` for the `ModelName` `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide where the source of truth for your data should be. In your current setup, it appears to be in `ModelNames`.

Instead of having `ModelName` perform the deletion, let `ModelNames` do it, since it owns the data.

Just pass a callback to `ModelName` that is called when deletion is requested. In this example we are adding a new property to the child component, `onRemove` which is called when the delete button is clicked:

```
var ModelNames = React.createClass({
  handleRemoveModelName: function(id) {
    // make Ajax call here
  },

  render: function() {
    var rows = this.state.model_names.map(function(model_name) {
      return (
        <ModelName 
          model_name={model_name}
          key={model_name.id}
          onRemove={this.handleRemoveModelName}
        />
      );
    }, this);

    // ...
   }
});

var ModelName = React.createClass({
  handleRemoveModelName: function() {
    this.props.onRemove(this.props.model_name.id);
  },
  // ...
});
```

The parent component can then decide how it wants to respond to this and make the appropriate Ajax call.

This makes `ModuleName` a "dump" component. It doesn't have any thing to do with data management and only renders the data it gets passed.

---

The other issue is that you are reading from the props in `ModelNames` (`this.props.model_names`), not the state. State and props are different. You need to read from the state (`this.state.model_names`) in order for the component to update when the state changes.

Comment: wow, thanks for the answer Felix - much appreciated. Going to give it a try just now.

Comment: Uh. I actually got confused with the component names. I just saw that you already use state in `ModelNames`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: yes that's right, sorry for the confusion, it's made worse by the generic name. I'm using plural for the table component and singular for an individual row.

Comment: Updated the answer. Less description but better solution :)

Comment: thank you again, just about to try it and fingers crossed it works/ I can figure out what I'm doing, and then I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Felix, I was getting an error so had to re-add `var rows = [];` and then do the iteration, after that the error went but the behaviour seemed to be the same as before - ajax request worked fine but the state didn't update to reflect the deletion. I will keep working on it just incase I've missed something from your answer.

Comment: You did move the Ajax call to `ModuleNames`, right? I forgot to update the body of the `.map` callback. You really should use `.map` here...

Comment: sure did, I'll update my question if you have a moment to look it over.

Comment: Ah stupid me. You are actually doing the same mistake in `ModuleNames` that I mentioned in the first version of my answer. You need to read from the state, not the props: `var rows = this.state.model_names.map(...)`.

Comment: ah, thank you so much, that's it working now. Had the same error again, not quite sure why actually, I'm using `<script type="text/babel">` and including the babel js file. I just had to do `var rows = [];` again before the iteration and it was fine.

Answer (score 3):

On top of Felix Kling's answer, you would need to somehow communicate between the `ModalNames` and `ModalName` to update the state, since the state is managed by `ModalNames` and the event is called in `ModalName`.

One solution is to pass function that updates the state to the `ModalName`:

ModalNames:

```
var ModelNames = React.createClass({
  ...
  updateState: function(modal_names) {
    this.setState({modal_names})
  },
  render: function() {
    var rows = [];

    this.state.model_names.forEach(function(model_name) {
      rows.push(<ModelName model_name={model_name} key={model_name.id} updateState={this.updateState} />);
    });
    ...
  }
}
```

ModalName:

```
var ModelName = React.createClass({
  handleRemoveModelName: function() {
    $.ajax({           
      url: '/model_name/ajax_delete', 
      data: { model_name_id: this.props.model_name.id },
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,           
      success: function(data) {
        this.props.updateState(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function() {
        console.log('error');      
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  ...
}
```

Alternative solution is to define `handleRemoveModelName` in `ModalNames` which takes in id, calls ajax, and does setState like you originally had.